# Найти два максимальных элемента массива C++

Tags: c++, массивы

Помогите. Задача описана в первых комментариях кода.
Никак не могу понять, как найти два максимальных элемента массива и их индекс.
Например, массив у нас пусть будет {10, -2, 3, 9, 7, 6, 2, -10, 9, 10}
Нужно чтобы показало элементы A[0] = 10 и A[9] = 10.

И ещё, поясните почему рандом постоянно генерирует одни и те же значения при компиляции.

```
// Задача: заполнить массив из 10 элементов случайными числами 
// в интервале [-10..10] и найти в нем 
// два максимальных элемента и их номера. 
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std; 

// Функция, возвращает случайное число в заданном диапазоне [a,b].
int random (int min, int max)
{
    max++;
    return abs(rand()%(max-min))+min;
}


int main()
{
    const int N = 10;
    int A[N], i, element, first_max_element, second_max_element, random_number_is, iMAX1, iMAX2;
    
    cout<<"Enter 5 elements of array.\n\n";
    
    // Заполняем массив рандомными числами.
    for(i =0; i<N; i++)
    {
        random_number_is = random(-10,10);
        A[i] = {random_number_is};
        cout<<"Random A["<<i<<"]: "<< random_number_is<<"\n";       
    }
    
    // Вычисляем первый максимальный элемент массива.
    first_max_element = A[0];
    iMAX1 = 0;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        if(A[i] > first_max_element)
        {
            first_max_element = A[i];
            iMAX1 = i;      
        }   
    }

    // Вычисляем второй максимальный элемент массива.
    second_max_element = A[0];
    iMAX2 = 0;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        if(A[i] > second_max_element && iMAX1 != iMAX2)
        {
            second_max_element = A[i];
            iMAX2 = i;      
        }
    }
    
    cout<<"\nFirst max element of array is: "<<"A["<<iMAX1<<"]: "<<first_max_element;
    cout<<"\nSecond max element of array is: "<<"A["<<iMAX2<<"]: "<<second_max_element;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если *все равно*, как искать - то вот пример с использованием стандартной библиотеки:

```
int main()
{
    const int N = 10;
    int a[N];

    srand(time(0));

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        cout << "a["<<i<<"] = " << (a[i] = rand()%21-10) << "\n";
    }

    partial_sort(a,a+2,a+N,greater<int>());

    cout << "First  max = " << a[0] << endl;
    cout << "Second max = " << a[1] << endl;

}
```

`rand()` создана так, что при каждом запуске программы она выдает одну и ту же последовательность - что полезно при отладке. Чтобы каждый раз шла новая последовательность - обычно генератор инициализируют текущим временем, например (см. `srand(time(0));` в исходнике выше).

Так устроит или вам надо по условию обязательно самому написать поиск, без привлечения стандартной библиотеки? Тогда

```
int max = a[0], max1 = a[0];

for(int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
{
    if (a[i] > max) { max1 = max; max = a[i]; }
    else if (a[i] > max1) { max1 = a[i]; }
}

cout << "First  max = " << max  << endl;
cout << "Second max = " << max1 << endl;
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли. Принцип работы не особо понял, но в свой код встроить смог)

Comment: В `max` - самое большое, в `max1` - второе. Новое число либо больше обоих, либо только второго, либо - ни одного. Все же разберитесь, просто "в свой код встроил" - не дело... И, если ответ устроил - то чтобы его принять, слева от него есть "птичка"...

Comment: Я сначала встраиваю, а вот сейчас и пытаюсь разобраться самостоятельно прогнав все числа через цикл в голове. Птичку нажал!!!